# How to mount a virtual disk in Linux (on VMWare)

Tags: linux, mount, vmware

I am running Ubuntu 10.04.4 thru VMWare Workstation. I added a second virtual hard disk drive, which is found under `/dev/sdb` , as shown below

[image]

How do you mount this to anywhere? (e.g. `/mnt/sdb`).

When I tried `sudo mount /dev/sdb /mnt/sdb -t ext4` 
I get the error message back

> wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb,
>          missing codepage or helper program, or other error
>          In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
>          dmesg | tail  or so

Comment: First of all, try to create partition on this disk. After that, you can mount partition with `mount` command.

Comment: @ymm even with this new, mounted hard drive, I still face the same problem as before. Unzip failed: No space left on device

Answer (score 2):

It isn't enough to create a new disk, you have to create a filesystem on it. The exact command used depends on the filesystem type, a command provided by Fedora is mkfs(8), a frontend to the various commands doing it for each filessytem type. Or it is called something like mke2fs (for ext2/3/4), mkxfs (for xfs), ... Check the release notes for your distribution to see what is recommended here.